# How to load Google Places API in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use the Google Places API in react native.  I first tried using `fetch` to make requests directly, but I just saw that you have to use the existing classes/objects provided by Google, like the `PlacesService`.  Searching for React Native libraries that include the API objects for you just brings up some that do the autocomplete feature and not  much else.

The Places API docs say to load the library using this url: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>`

This is straightforward to me in regular web dev, but not in react native.  What is the standard procedure for loading a library like this in React Native?

Right now I have copy and pasted the JS contents from the link above into a file in my React Native project.  But, I don't even know how to export it as I can't really tell what the name of the object/function is.  google ? google.maps ?

Right now I am doing:

```
export default google.maps
```

and also tried

```
export default google
```

but these both throw this error:

```
cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
```

This is my first React Native project, so I'm sorry if this is a basic question.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`but I just saw that you have to use the existing classes/objects provided by Google`

I'm not sure what you mean by that. Places api can be done via fetch/api request. Look at how `react-native-google-places` does it at https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/blob/master/GooglePlacesAutocomplete.js#L227
They use a `new XMLHttpRequest();` but `fetch()` would work as well. It is web api and I don't think you need to run any external javascript/load any external js files.

Comment: Agree, places is just a http api, no need for a third-party package here

Comment: When I was using fetch I got a 200 ok response, but calling .results on it was undefined, and I asked a question about it with google-places tag and a commenter said to use the PlacesService.  I'll try again i guess.

Comment: @srlrs20020 could you link that question? I couldn't find it in your history. Perhaps you was missing something, convert response to json?

Comment: @TravisWhite You have to convert the response to JSON?  I specified json as the request type, do you still have to convert it?  I was able to access the keys that were on the response, but "results" was not one of them.  The available keys were: type,status,ok,statusText,headers,url,_bodyInit,_bodyText.  There was a results object in bodyInit and bodyText, but I couldn't access it.  Is what I should convert?   Sorry I should have mentioned I deleted the question.

Comment: Yeah, `let res = await fetch(`${API_URL}${stuff}`);` and then `res = await res.json();`

Comment: @TravisWhite  how do you specify a location using just HTTP?  I am currently doing location=<lat>,<long> in the url, but am not getting real results from the API.  The docs say a location "takes a google.maps.LatLng object".  I thought I saw yesterday you could just specify location=<lat>,<long> but I can't find it anymore..

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/ which has `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670,151.1957&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY` as default example query...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161526/discussion-between-srlrs20020-and-travis-white).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like reading the accepted answer the procedure isn't obvious. So I'll add my 2 cents here:
The url provided by the OP (e.g `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places`) is for web and web only. When fetched, it'll try to add google-maps functions to the Window object. I don't think copy/paste the returned value would be such a good idea as you'd be stuck with the sdk version that you primarily fetched, not to say that the data returned is uglified so you'll have trouble understanding what's going on.
As mentionned by @TravisWhite in a previous comment, the [places web-service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service) provides an API such as `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json`, `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json`, or `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json` that you can call using the library of your choice (Axios, Fetch, XMLHttpRequest, etc...)